# How to get Xlib code work in eclipse for C++ ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, xlib

I have some code with the following headers for Xlib but don't know what to do to make it work...I can't find these headers.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
```

Sorry new to this..
Okay so now I can view the headers in the foldrrs in my eclipse IDE.
and i get the following errors.Thee is no problem with the source as friends have run it from the terminal,and i want to do it from eclipse ide:

In function `main':
/home/abbas/workspace/test3/Debug/../src/test3.cpp:51: undefined reference to`XOpenDisplay'

and many other errors of the same type but the functions are different.

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test3] Error 1

Plzz hellpp!!

Comment: #include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>

Comment: Surely you see the edit button, the preview, etc...? I don't understand. In any case, have you considered [*installing* X11](http://www.wikihow.com/Configure-X11-in-Linux)?

Comment: yes i did..this solved the problem to a great extent but it gave some new errors

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
undefined reference to `XDrawLine' test3.cpp /test3/src line 141 C/C++ Problem
This is probably a link error but I dont know how to link Xlib to my project in eclipse...and im using eclipse c++ for ubuntu

Comment: Edit your question to ask your question. Use comments to add comments. Don't use comments to ask questions.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on Project Folder> Properties> C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Linker > Libraries > add "X11"